# make mysql use view on join

Tags: mysql, join, view

Is it possible to create a view and make mysql use it internaly each time when join is required. The background of this question is I don't want to change the application which uses joins but want to speed up the queries

Comment: Can you be more specific? For instance, show the tables that are being joined?

Comment: You can use views in joins, but you have to specify view's name. You can't make mysql use it "internally" in some smart way, you need to explicitly specify the view's name and that's it.

Comment: I'm not sure a view would speed you up. Indexes may be more what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't say to mysql use view if some query uses joins. 
For speeding up your queries you should:

1. Enable mysql slow query log.
2. Check each query from this one using explain.
3. Try to add indexes if it's necessary.